# How to install the old version of PHPUNIT?

Tags: php, centos, phpunit

We have a Centos 6.3 machine running PHP 5.3.3. I accidentally uninstalled PHPUNIT. I am not able to reinstall it again. The newer versions do not work with PHP 5.3.3. Unfortunately, I cannot update my PHP version (company is stuck). How do I fix it?

I tried:

```
$ wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
$ chmod +x phpunit.phar
$ sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
$ phpunit --version
```

as suggested and it is not working.

Comment: Looking at https://phar.phpunit.de, you should be able to specify the version, e.g. `wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-3.7.10.phar`

Comment: Thanks kingkero, your suggestion worked. Please post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So I simply took a look at https://phar.phpunit.de and as you can see there, you can specify the version number you want to install, eg.

```
$ wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-4.8.9.phar
```

However, I'd recommend using Composer where you can specify version numbers as well (described in the [doc](https://phpunit.de/manual/4.8/en/index.html))

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.8.*"
    }
}
```

Using Composer brings many advantages. One of them is that you can make sure that the same version of a library is used by everyone working on the project (without having to share all the vendor files!)

Comment: And English documentation for older versions of PHPUnit may be found at: https://phpunit.de/manual/4.8/en/. Replace `4.8` with the version you'd like to learn more about.

Comment: it not working for me! can someone help?

Comment: @SunilPrajapati What does "not working" mean? Which method have you tried and what errors do you get? It might make sense to create a new question, referencing this one and explaining in detail what you tried and where it failed.

Comment: @kero Sorry, i had latest version installed with homebrew, that's why it wasnt working. its fine now.

Answer (score 7):

kero's answer is great, however I want to add an example of using phpunit in one deprecated script in our company

```
{
  "require": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "*",
    "php": ">=5.3.17"
  }
}
```

It install latest supported version (4.8.35 in this case) for PHP 5.3.17 after composer update and can't be used something like this:

> ./vendor/bin/phpunit SomeTest.php

Comment: Thanks ! That helped me A LOT !